# Вопрос по Steam API

Tags: php, javascript, json, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли получить через Steam API список названий всех имеющихся скинов на данный момент по игре CS-GO? Интересуют только имена, искал, но что-то не нашел такого.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нельзя, у них апи вообще скудное, парсить разве что торговую площадку, и то все названия не получить

Comment: Эх, жаль, ладно, спасибо, буду тогда искать другой путь

Comment: Привет. Вижу вопрос по STEAM API. Вопрос, есть ли у Вас возможность скинуть код авторизации на сайт Steam`а ? Или же просто объяснить как мне самому можно разобраться с документацией ? Нашёл по этой ссылке : https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/steam.webauth.html